# Удалить содержание папки, но не саму папку

Tags: c++, файлы, файловая-система

Как удалить содержимое папки, если мне не подходит способ с удалением папки и созданием папки с таким же названием?

Comment: А при чём тут c++?

Comment: Alexey Ten, ну я делаю это на C++

Comment: Уточните ОС в вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если вариант с удалением всего вместе с каталогом не годится - воспользуйтесь [`directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) или [`recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) - что вам лучше подходит - и удалите все файлы в цикле.